# If Z= aX+b with two contants a,b belongs to real numbers and E[Z]=0, V(Z) =1, find a and b.

Tags: statistics

In this question I tried the approach as
since,
       E[Z]=0
       E[Z]=a*E[X]+b
       E[X]= -b/a

```
   V[Z]=1  
   V(Z)=a^2*V(X)  
   V(X)=1/a^2
```

I am stuck after this.

Comment: [reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/306553) for maths typesetting on this site.

Answer (score 1):

Solving for $a$,$$a=\pm\frac1{\sqrt{V(X)}}$$

then substitute to the first condition that you found.
$$b = -aE[X]=\mp \frac{E[X]}{\sqrt{V(X)}}$$

I think the purpose of the exerise is to construct that

$$\pm\frac{X-E(X)}{\sqrt{V(X)}}$$ has mean $0$ and variance $1$.

Comment: but I am still unable to find the values of a and b... first i thought that a=1 and b=0, but that's also not correct.

Comment: erm.... I have given you the answer, $a = \pm \frac1{\sqrt{V(X)}}$

Comment: yeaa... but according to this answer isin't correct... and also I don't know the correct answer.

Comment: what is the source of the question?

Comment: Its a  question from a random exercise i got through on internet. I have 4 attempts to solve this and i have used 3 attempts

Comment: I see. well, sometimes, they could be looking for certain formatting. or they are expecting just a single pair of solution.

Comment: They are just expecting a single solution which belongs to real numbers

Comment: do you know anything about $X$?

Comment: No.. that's the reason that I am stuck as there is no other information given in the question